# COLLATE NOCASE bug?

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently on Android 5.x my app is having issues with an SQLite query. There seem to be an issue with `ORDER BY " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_CATEGORY + " COLLATE NOCASE`. This is causing my query to exclude some items from the results. Removing this particular part causes the issue to disappear. This wasn't an issue until Android 5.x :(

Any tips or ideas how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full query:

```
// query for total categories
String queryTotalCat = 
    "SELECT _id, NULL as " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_CATEGORY + ", " +
    "COUNT(*) as " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_COUNT + " " +
    "FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
    "WHERE " + KEY_TYPE_FAVORITE + "!=0";

// query for total count of each repeated categories
String queryTotalRows =
    "SELECT _id, " + KEY_CATEGORY + " as " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_CATEGORY + ", " +
    "COUNT(" + KEY_CATEGORY + ") as " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_COUNT + " " +
    "FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
    "WHERE " + KEY_TYPE_FAVORITE + "!=0";

// union the two queries
String query = 
    queryTotalCat + " UNION " + queryTotalRows + " " +
    "ORDER BY "+ KEY_TEMP_CAT_CATEGORY + " " +
    "COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
```

Comment: Can you isolate and provide few sample rows that we can put into our testing table and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Well, I did do an isolated test and was able to remove the UNION to include only one SELECT query. I'll update the question with more info when I get to my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried simplifying the query to see where exactly things weren't working and I was able to find a couple things.

**COUNT**
The COUNT call was actually missing GROUP BY call to specify the column I need grouping to happen on.

**UNION**
The order in which I place the two SELECT calls on the UNION was also the key to resolve the issue. The complex compound SELECT call with GROUP BY needed to be placed first and then simpler SELECT call.

**Modified working query**

```
// query for total categories
String queryTotalCat = 
    "SELECT " +
        "0 AS _id," +
        "NULL AS " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_CATEGORY + "," +
        "COUNT(*) AS " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_COUNT +
    " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + 
    " WHERE " + KEY_TYPE_FAVORITE + "=1";

// query for total count of each repeated categories
String queryTotalRows =
    "SELECT " + 
        "_id, " + 
        KEY_CATEGORY + " AS " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_CATEGORY + "," +
        "COUNT(" + KEY_CATEGORY + ") AS " + KEY_TEMP_CAT_COUNT + 
    " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
    " WHERE " + KEY_TYPE_FAVORITE + "=1" +
    " GROUP BY " + KEY_CATEGORY;

// union the two queries
String query = 
        queryTotalRows + " UNION " + queryTotalCat +
    " ORDER BY "+ KEY_TEMP_CAT_CATEGORY + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
```